# Having the millenium digit on a separate column from the rest of the date. Why would they do that?

Tags: date, db2

I'm working on this old application from the 80's. It runs on a DB2 backbone and I just noticed something weird on several tables: The date is split in two columns with one column having only the millenium digit like so...

```
DATECOL1    DATECOL2
========    ========
       2     0070123
```

What unholy ancient black magic is this? I asked a colleague and he said "I don't know, 80's thing probably".

So I guess I'm asking the old timers out there, is there some arcane reason for doing this you all knew about or is it just a quirk of this particular app? I know you probably can't tell for sure without more context, but if you have an idea just shoot it. I don't really need 100% certainty, I'm just curious about the practice.

Comment: Have you seen this in a banking application?

Comment: No, its not banking related. Why?

Comment: Because I've seen that thing as a y2k "solution" in many banking apps, relaying on DB2.

Comment: Quite bizarre really as DB2 has had a splendid "DATE" type since the 1980s. Probably some extremely lazy conversion of a previous flat file based system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many apps did not have a millennium before 2000. The millennium column was probably added as part of a y2k initiative in the late 90s. Many apps in the 60s through 80s were not expected to last until 2000.
To do these y2k efforts many retired mainframe COBOL programmers came out of retirement for 100/hr consulting gigs.
The doomsday naysayers were predicting the end of the world. Nuclear weapons would fail or utilities might shutdown or the stock markets would crash.

Comment: Sweet paycheck that.

Y2K was the first thing I thought of, but then that means they were storing the dates as yymmdd, so why the extra digit in the old column?

Comment: @cptaj actually the format of the column is CYYMMDD where the c is 0 for 1900 and 1 for 2000. What u see now is an artifact of a newer db/2 version.